# How to solve the unexpected token error in my jsx?

Tags: webpack, reactjs

I am using reactjs and this is part of my componentcode:

```
  myType() {
        return myComponent;
  }
  render() {
              return (
                <div className="row">
                    {
                       let thisType = this.myType;
                       return (<thisType />)
                    }
                </div>
            );
  }
```

When I run my code I get this error:

```
BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: ../.../myComponent.js: Unexpected token (47:19
```

This is pointing to the let statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the name of the component outside of JSX and put it in a variable with the first letter capitalised (that's how JSX determines whether it's a custom component):

```
myType() {
    return myComponent;
}

render() {
    let ThisType = this.myType();

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <ThisType />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try

```
<div className='row'>
   { this.myType() }
</div>
```